# Sakila db SQL find customers who have rented >10 horror movies

Tags: mysql

I am totally stuck on my homework. I am working with the Sakila sample db. I am supposed to write a query that will give me a list of all the customers who have rented >10 horror movies. This is what I have so far:

```
select CONCAT(c.first_name, " ", c.last_name) AS "Customer name", 
FROM customer AS c

INNER JOIN rental AS r
ON c.customer_id = r.customer_id

inner join  inventory as i
on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id

inner join  film_category as fc
on i.film_id = fc.film_id
 inner join 
(select * from category as ca
where ca.name = 'horror') as h
 on h.category_id = fc.category_id 
 ;
```

I can get it to return **all** (846) of the customers who have rented horror movies, but how do I get only those who have rented more than 10 horror movies? I know I need the COUNT function, but when I put it in, it gives me 1 person, and a count of 846, which is a count of people, not horror movies rented. My logic is just failing me at this point. Help please!

Comment: Besides `COUNT` you need to use [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) so you can separate results by customer and [`HAVING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) to get only the ones with >10

Comment: @darkajax - Please do not add the homework tag, this tag is OBSOLETE and is in the process of being removed. Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) question on Meta for more information.

Comment: @Mike got it, sorry won't do it again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don’t know the sample database in question. However, I feel that this isn't going to affect my response for this question.

If you want to use COUNT you will need to also use [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) to achieve an aggregate count.

You could also look at [GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) with a [HAVING](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=mysql%20having&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC8QFjAA&url=http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html&ei=VVs2UeraL8KYPceJgZgF&usg=AFQjCNFA7IECBXCwroBX9IcLvCxeD76e-A) clause.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone need easy meal:

```
SELECT R.customer_id, COUNT(*) AS cnt 
FROM sakila.rental R LEFT JOIN sakila.inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
LEFT JOIN sakila.film F ON I.film_id = F.film_id 
LEFT JOIN sakila.film_category FC on F.film_id = FC.film_id 
LEFT JOIN sakila.category C ON FC.category_id = C.category_id 
WHERE C.name = "Horror" 
GROUP BY R.customer_id HAVING cnt > 10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a query without left join/inner join as well. Note that there is no customer that has more than 10 horror rentals, so having a blank result should not confuse you (Try with 2 and it works!)

```
SELECT cu.first_name, cu.last_name, COUNT(r.rental_id) as horror_film_count
FROM customer AS cu, rental AS r, inventory as i, film as f, category as ca, 
film_category as fc
WHERE cu.customer_id = r.customer_id 
AND r.inventory_id = i.inventory_id
AND i.film_id = f.film_id
AND f.film_id = fc.film_id
AND fc.category_id = ca.category_id
AND ca.category_id = 11
GROUP BY cu.customer_id
HAVING horror_film_count > 10
```